# What does "share selection" do in Firefox

Tags: firefox

By default, Firefox has a `Share Selection` contextual menu (right-click) item. Between the `Search Provider for "..."` and the `View Selection Source` options when highlighting text.

Searching about this feature reveals a mixture of bug reports and, thankfully, advice to remove this by moving the Share This Page item from the menu into the additional tools are. However, there is no information about what it actually does.

I only searched after accidentally clicking it, so what did it do? Did it send the highlighted data elsewhere?

Comment: Simply to say you can activate sharing the services have a look at this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Social_API/Share.

Answer (score 0):

Well the thing is its just a share button if we select some words or and image then click on this share selection a small box will pop up at the top of firefox where it says "You can activate Share services from the directory. TAKE ME THERE " so it will take you to

https://activations.cdn.mozilla.net/en-US/

and in there you can activate your share services like Facebook Twitter LinkedIn. (if you have signed in with a mozilla account)

thats all

Comment: So, as I have not set anything up, it did nothing?

Comment: ya it did nothing , you have to config before any thing to happen